# Difference in result ( MySQL 5.7 vs MySQL 8.0 ) when using group_by and offset limit

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

I'm wondering why this query shows different results in different versions of MySQL when I change offset. This is my query

```
SELECT 
  users.partner_id, 
  users_summaries.total_count,
  users.last_working_date
FROM 
  `users` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      user_loc_summaries.partner_id, 
      user_loc_summaries.loc_id, 
      SUM(
        user_loc_summaries.total_count
      ) AS total_count 
    FROM 
      user_loc_summaries 
    WHERE 
      (
        user_loc_summaries.loc_id = '2222' 
      ) 
    GROUP BY
      user_loc_summaries.partner_id
  ) AS users_summaries ON (
    users_summaries.partner_id = users.partner_id
  ) 
WHERE 
  AND `users`.`loc_id` IN (2222, 666, 666)
GROUP BY 
  users.partner_id 
ORDER BY 
  (
    users.loc_id = '2222'
  ) DESC, 
  users.loc_id ASC, 
  users.last_working_date desc 
LIMIT 
  10 OFFSET 0
```

- last_working_date can be null (in my database last_working_date almost is null)
- On version 5.7 when I change the offset (for pagination) the result always uniq
- On version 8 when I change the offset the results is overlaps with previous pages

I know that using group_by without order_by may cause this problem. But I don't know why mysql version 5.7  return the correct results?

Comment: With out tables and data we really can not reproduce your problem

Comment: Have installed the he latest version of MySQL 8

Comment: @nbk I'm testing on `MySQL 8.0.34` and 5.7

Comment: 8.0.36 is the last version try to update it

Comment: Overlapping suggests that you don't have a fully deterministic order. Last ordered by column is a date, and dates are typically not unique. Also, you have both DISTINCT and GROUP BY, and you are selecting columns you don't group by, what means that MySQL will pick an arbitrary match.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I know that using group_by without order_by (group key column) may cause this problem. But I don't know why mysql version 5.7 return the correct results? What is different abount 5.7 and 8.0?

Comment: Because that's what "undefined behaviour" or "arbitrary row" imply. If you give MySQL freedom to choose rows, you'll get non deterministic result sets. Any change in how the records are physically stored on disk or MySQL optimizer engine will produce different results.

Comment: Note that `DISTINCT` is a modifier which applies to the whole row, not a function as your query formatting would appear to suggest. Are `user_loc_summaries.partner_id` and `users.partner_id` unique (UNIQUE INDEX or PRIMARY KEY), or do you have ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY disabled?

Comment: Thank for your support, I've found different of 5.7 and 8.0 and resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

> In MySQL, historically GROUP BY was used to provide sorting as well. If a query specified GROUP BY, the result was sorted as if ORDER BY was present in the query.

https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/removal-of-implicit-and-explicit-sorting-for-group-by/

In mysql 5.7 column gourp_by was sorting as well (default asc), and from mysql 8.0.13 it was removed so that why using limit, offset with group_by without order_by (group_by column) return correct results.